# CentOS 8.3 kickstart text only install timezone problem

Tags: linux, centos, kickstart

I have a custom text install using kickstart (ks.cfg) for CentOS 8.3.  The problem I'm having is with timezone setting in ks.cfg.  timezone is required in ks.cfg, so in previous version of CentOS, the install would stop to ask for timezone because it wasn't present in ks.cfg. If you comment out the timezone setting in ks.cfg it will now automatically assign NY timezone and continue with the install automatically (text based install).  This has to be a bug unless there is another setting I don't know about to make the install stop to ask the installer for the timezone.  In the graphical install of CentOS 8.3 NY also seems to be the default setting.  I need to have the text based install stop so that the installer set the proper timezone instead of having it automatically plug in NY timezone and continue with the install without stopping.

Here is where the install should stop instead of plugging in New York timezone:

NOTE: In this example, timezone is commented out in ks.cfg

[image]

### UPDATE

I tried putting bad timezone data in ks.cfg and it still lets the install begin without flagging it as an invalid timezone.

```
# timezone
timezone Gibberish/Stuff --isUtc --nontp
```

[image]

Comment: I still think this is a bug.  Filing a bug is such a time consuming deal that I've got no time for that.  The answer is here anyways.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found my answer.  In order to force a text install to stop for user input on `timezone` instead of using the default `America/New York`, specify `timezone` in `ks.cfg` in the following way with `""` for timezone parameter:

ks.cfg `timezone` setting:

```
# timezone
timezone "" --nontp
```

If you comment out `timezone` or try to use `timezone --nontp` without the quotes, the installer will automatically assign `America/New York` as a timezone and will not stop at the screen below to prompt the user for a timezone.  Since all the installation criteria has been satisfied, the install begins automatically without stopping when `America/New York` is plugged in automatically.

[image]

In the example above, the install has stopped and the user can select `2)` from the menu and set the `timezone` for the system. After setting the `timezone`, the user can select `b` to begin the custom installation.

Comment: if I would do ks install, i would prefer that installer would not stop to ask questions if it is unattended install. Perhaps that was the idea...

Comment: Yep, after all, it is an automatic installer...In my case, the custom install might be installed in many different `timezones` so it's up to the person installing to choose the `timezone` for the system.